# How to Automate an SQL Script on a windows machine where the "date" in the script has to be new every run

Tags: sql, mysql, windows-task-scheduler

I currently am manually running a SQL report every week where I only have to change one line in the SQL to represent the next Fridays date.

What would be the best way to automate this?

Currently I can use windows task scheduler to run the report and then send said report via e-mail. I am just stuck on how to set up variable dates

Below is a snipping of the line in question where I would need to alter the date only

`where  dbo.orders.customerID = '2' AND dbo.orders.OrderDueDate = '2023-04-21' AND dbo.orders.id = dbo.blinds.orderid`

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL, not SQL-Server? `dbo` is a SQL-Server convention.